# typescript + express: How to pass middleware response to a function?

Tags: typescript, express

I am using `"compression"` with Express. How do I provide the type to pass the response type to a helper function?

`app.ts`

```
import express from "express";
import compression from "compression";

const app = express();
app.use(compression());

/* Do not need to specify types for req/res. They are inferred from the signature of `get`.  */
app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
  });
  res.flushHeaders();

  for (let c of "hello") {
    const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(c)}\n\n`;
    res.write(data);
    res.flush(); // From "@types/compression"
  }
  res.end();
});

const port = 12345;
console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
console.log(`Run: curl localhost:${port}/hello`);
app.listen(port);
```

Attempted wrappers:

```
/* What if you mix up the argument order. This is no good. */
function writeData_any(res: any, data: any) {
  data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`;
  res.write(data);
  res.flush();
}
/* Property 'write' does not exist on type 'Response'.ts(2339) */
// function writeData_1(res: Express.Response, data: any) {
//   data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`;
//   res.write(data);
//   res.flush();
// }

/* Intellisence on `get` below:
 * (parameter) res: Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
 *
 * BUT
 * Type 'Response' is not generic.ts(2315)
 * interface Express.Response
 */
// function writeData_2(
//   res: Express.Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>,
//   data: any
// ) {
//   data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`;
//   res.write(data);
//   res.flush();
// }

/* Typescript isn't C++ templates */
// function writeData_3<R>(res: R, data: any) {
//   data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`;
//   res.write(data);
//   res.flush();
// }
/* Could, but shouldn't need to write this. */
interface R {
  write: CallableFunction;
  flush: CallableFunction;
}
function writeData_4(res: R, data: any) {
  data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`;
  res.write(data);
  res.flush();
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "Node16",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17"
  }
}
```

---

I see other questions asking how to add type to *their* middleware to express, but I already have the types for the middleware in use. I just don't know to use them in my function.